# Sharing a webpage with embedded YouTube video won't share webpage text

Tags: youtube, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I've added a Facebook "Like" button to my website and I'm sharing posts with embedded YouTube videos.

The problem is that these shared pages on Facebook are just displaying the video preview image and webpage title. It doesn't display the webpage text. Note that I'm not trying to get the video itself to share, just the preview image, webpage title and description.

The weird thing is SOME of my YouTube video posts will extract the description from the webpage. All other shared posts from my website work fine.

As for some examples...

http://mantrasoftware.net/2011/09/02/staind-not-again-official-video/ - This page will only show the preview image and webpage title when shared to Facebook.

http://mantrasoftware.net/2011/08/29/trackmania-2-canyon-educational-video/ - This page shows the preview image, webpage title AND the webpage description (post text).

I can't figure out where these 2 pages differ for Facebook "Like" purposes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding the og description tag.

More info can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

This description tag contains what shall be the post text.

Comment: I just noticed the description tag was missing. Thanks for bringing that up. It's added now and it works fine. Still confused as to why it would work sometimes and not others though.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, Facebook is not that stable when it comes to the sharer, it often has moments when it's not working correctly. It even had plenty of bugs dealing with sites with correct og tags. Stuff like this happen from time to time, it's better to get used to it and, if you are an active developer, check this site or their bug tracker to see what sort of new bugs emerge

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add some extra meta tags to your pages...
You can read about the [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) for more details...
Basically you need to add these tags to your page -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
    ...
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: I've read that page and thought I had all the tags needed. For some reason the description tag wasn't being generated and added to the page. It seems to be fixed now. Thanks.